# How do I install Reporting Services for an already existing SQL Server 2008 database?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to figure out how to install Reporting Services for a SQL Server 2008 instance that is already installed and running but can only figure out how to install it for a new database.

Can somebody please provide some assistance and let me know how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Insert the original installation media, and there should be an option in the install wizard to add features to your existing installation.